# How to insert from a customyplugin.php file an automatic directive to the .htaccess file - WORDPRESS

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-rest-api

I ask you help to understand how to make a function that allows me to write inside the .htaccess file and insert the following header.

in practice i can't understand how to write from a custom plugin a function that if the .htaccess file already exists it will insert the following code.

can you help me thanks for the help

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>


 <Directory />
    Header always set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header always set x-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
    Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
    Header always set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; font-src *;img-src * data:; script-src *; style-src *;"
    Header always set Referrer-Policy "strict-origin"
  </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

ff

Comment: Does this help? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/331608/how-can-i-code-my-plugin-to-safely-modify-htaccess

Comment: hi @CBroe, Searching I had found the code you shared with me but it doesn't do what I wanted in the sense I would like a plugin I made called /security to add to the .htaccess file above or at the bottom a directive as I wrote above without deleting already the directives in the htaccess.

but i can't solve the problem on how to update / add inside the file that code

Answer (score 0):

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36233/how-to-add-htaccess-code-through-a-function#36239

here is what i would like to do but for some reason it doesn't work i took Geert's code but if i make a $insertion with arrey value it doesn't go i don't know what to do i have no more ideas or if it just needs to be improved the code

```
 function hed_htaccess($rules ) {
$content = <<<EOD
#Enable Vary: Accept-Encoding Start
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
EOD;
return $content . $rules; }
add_filter('mod_rewrite_rules', 'hed_htaccess');
```

Comment: Hi! Please update your original question. This is not a forum. People would like your whole question, including solutions you have tried, in the original question text. Feel free to edit the question. 